# a sata3 hard drive not recognized on a usb2 port

Tags: mount

I am trying to read a sata3 hard drive on a usb2 port but the drive isn't found.  I've tried on several computers.  Is this a compatibility issue?

Comment: How are you connecting it to the USB port?  A USB to SATA adapter?  What happens when you connect it, does the USB adapter show up in `lsusb`?

Comment: Does hard drive have separate power or only thru USB port. Many HDD drives need more power than USB port provides. I have an USB adapter & a  small SSD works well, but HDD will not spin up.

Comment: Is this a HDD that's recently been placed into an external USB disk drive case? If so, what size HDD, and does the external case have its own power adapter? Does gparted see the drive?

Answer (score 0):

I tried different connectors and tried on different computers.  I got it to work finally but I don't know how.  The drive seems to come and go for no apparent reason.  Something is flaky somewhere.  I have some diagnosis to do now.
Thanks for all your help